# Deploy a SpringBoot App on Tomcat as a WAR package

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I need my SpringBoot application to run on the client as a service, so I am trying to deploy it inside Tomcat, version 9 ... but it is not working
As I'm a beginner I followed some tutorials and modified my main extended **SpringBootServletInitializer** and overriding the method:

```
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    return builder.sources(BwsApplication.class);
}
```

POM

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.speedsoft</groupId>
<artifactId>bedelServer</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>bedel</name>
<description>BWS</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <quartz.version>2.2.1</quartz.version>
    <jooq.version>3.9.1</jooq.version>
    <logback.version>1.2.3</logback.version>
    <logbackaccess.version>1.3.0-alpha4</logbackaccess.version>
    <mysql.version>6.0.3</mysql.version>
    <exec-maven-plugin>1.7</exec-maven-plugin>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
       <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>${quartz.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
        <version>${quartz.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
        <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
        <version>${jooq.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
        <artifactId>jooq-meta</artifactId>
        <version>${jooq.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
        <artifactId>jooq-codegen</artifactId>
        <version>${jooq.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
        <version>${logbackaccess.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${exec-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.speedsoft.bws.BwsApplication</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Main

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BwsApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logs.class);
    private ConfigClass config;

    public BwsApplication (ConfigClass configClass) {
        config = configClass;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BwsApplication.class, args);
   }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(BwsApplication.class);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            con = config.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error(e.toString());
        }
         QuartzApp qa = new QuartzApp(config);
         qa.excecution();
    }
}
```

TomCat LOG

```
12-Dec-2018 16:52:23.609 GRAVE [http-nio-8090-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Error during ServletContainerInitializer processing
 javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5098)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:492)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1651)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:294)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:212)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:607)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:348)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.speedsoft.bws.BwsApplication.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.accessibleConstructor(ReflectionUtils.java:503)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:155)
    ... 47 more

12-Dec-2018 16:52:23.611 GRAVE [http-nio-8090-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/bedelServer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] startup failed due to previous errors
12-Dec-2018 16:52:23.710 INFORMAÇÕES [http-nio-8090-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\bedelServer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war] has finished in [15,986] ms
```

If I do not extend the class and do not insert override the SpringApplicationBuilder method my application normally goes up in intellij

Comment: which log of tomcat, catalina.out?

Comment: do not override SpringApplicationBuilder () just  extends SpringBootServletInitializer  then it will work

Comment: Spring tries to find a constructor without argument on your class `BwsApplication`.

Comment: @GaneshGudghe 
I removed the method but the error persists

Comment: @Selaron 
Can you give me an idea how to solve?

Comment: declare empty constructor

Comment: @GaneshGudghe  with empty constructor 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer

Comment: Do you want to create `war` file ?

Comment: @AvijitBarua 
I created the WAR file, without errors the problem is at the time of doing deploy since I need to run tomCat as a service

Comment: pay attention to: "Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.speedsoft.bws.BwsApplication.<init>()"

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
@Autowired
private ConfigClass config;
```

Then you can remove the

```
public BwsApplication (ConfigClass configClass) {
    config = configClass;
}
```

Hope this one helps

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [this link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html).

You can easily found how to install Spring Boot application as a service without any external servlet container.